# How to organise pushpin with WPF bing map control

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

I am building a Desktop touch application using the WPF bing maps control.
I have seen that you can add  element directly as an item to the map control or if using MVVM we can use the MapItemControls and define a binding to a collection of Location.

For my scenario I will display on the map different type of information like :

- Location of customer projects in different Location . projects are organise by type ( Big project, medium project, Validated project )
- Location of customer sales offices

PushpPins will be visualy identified differently based on Project type and Sales Office.

The question I have, is about the way to organise those pushpins on the map .

Do I have to go to a single ObservableCollection of Location which will contains Projects Location and Sales area and display them all in a single maplayer ?

Do I better go to create a MapLayer for each PushPin type and bind them to respective collection ?

What is the best ?

regards
serge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by using different map layers